# "reserved word in the urls" error in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, reserved-words

This is my error message:

```
{"requestId":"b29fdb37-816d-4cde-b8ee-a9181f27a7a4","errorCode":"InstanceReservedWordNotAllowedInEntryKey","errorMessage":"Entry key \"https://________/BWBR0005537/2023-08-01/#___________1.1_Artikel1:2\" contains reserved word \":\""}
```

This is my code snippet for related issue:

```
import urllib.parse

if not pd.isnull(row['resource']) and isinstance(row['resource'], str) and row['resource'].strip() != "":
    url = row['resource']
    
    # Encode special characters in the URL
    encoded_url = urllib.parse.unquote(url)

    url_updated = encoded_url
    # url_updated = url
    if not (url.startswith("http://") or url.startswith("https://")):
        url_updated = "http://" + url_updated  # Prepend 'http://' if it is not there
    term.resources = [{
        "displayName": url,
        "url": url_updated
    }]
```

How can handle with this issue?

Comment: The error message seems to be caused by some API call which isn't present in the shown code.

Comment: The URL appears to end in `1_Artikel1:2` which some unseen process is rejecting because it contains a colon. You might need to URL-encode this to %3A.

Comment: Should I replace the ":" with "%3A"

Comment: Michael Butscher, I use the code snippet in create_glossary_term function and I am calling the function as below:                                                                                        for index, row in filtered_parent_df.iterrows():
    if row['Amsterdam term'] in different_terms_parent:
        term = create_glossary_term(row, default_glossary, steward_json)
        terms_to_upload_parent.append(term)

Comment: Please show how you make the API call. If you use the `requests` module it should automatically encode parameters.